# pi1, armv6, how to disable armhf packages?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, apt

I dusted off a Pi 1, which is armv6, then installed Raspbian on it. The base OS works, but many of the packages I install won't even start- they say `illegal instruction`. That's because the armhf binary packages are being installed, which isn't compatible with the Pi1.

Here's an example, looking at vim-common in `apt show`:

```
...
Download-Size: 339 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stable/main armhf Packages
Description: Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```

Aside from installing an ancient kernel, how do I tell apt to not install the 'wrong' version of the binaries?

Here's what my sources.list contains (in part). Nowhere does it say armv6, armv7, armel, or armhf.

`$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_raspbian_org_raspbian.list
deb https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  As far as I am aware Raspbian will run okay on all Pis.  I don't have any problems with my original Pi B (the first model).

Comment: The original Pi B is `armel` only, I think. To compare Pis, what does `dpkg --print-architecture` say on your Pi1B?

Comment: I used to use armel as that was all that Debian supported.  I now use armhf which is what is reported.  Remember that the whole raison d'être of Raspbian was to provide armhf.

Comment: Sure, but .. the Zero and Pi1 don't grok armhf. Hence the question.

Comment: @tedder42 - Sorry, you are absolutely wrong. The Zero and Pi1 absolutely **do** grok armhf - I have 776 packages installed on my **original** (256MB) Pi1 - 385 of them include `:armhf` in the package name, the other 391 are not CPU specific, that leaves **ZERO** that are `:armel` - similar results for a ZeroW - read https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=80566 and you'll see **all** Pi grok armhf

Comment: to use your example of `vim` ... look [here](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/v/vim/) - absolutely no `armel` versions of vim even exist in the raspbian apt repository

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both Raspbian and Debian pride themselves in suppporting the "armhf" architecture. **Of course, they mean two different things !**

- Raspbian "armhf": ARMv6 + VFPv2
- Debian "armhf": ARMv7

**Your scenario is impossible without mixing debian.org and raspbian.org/raspberrypi.org packages.** You must have mixed those repositories in the past or are still using mixed up repositories.

Check the output of

```
apt-cache policy name-of-offending-package
```

**Raspbian "armhf" has always worked on any Raspberry Pi.** Debian "armhf" only works on newer Pis with ARMv7 CPU (first released ~ 2015).

Comment: that totally explains it! I couldn't figure out the armhf weirdness. I was bootstrapping in the debian packages. I was including `deb.debian.org/debian` and `archive.raspberrypi.org/debian`; I assume both need to go?

Comment: `debian.org` must go. `debian.org` repos are considered harmful for Raspbian systems ;) `raspbian.org/raspberrypi.org` are fine, even if it says "armhf"